# Is this girl really Slaanesh?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Is the woman in this [image](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/File:Slaanesh-153102-SweetAngel.jpg) really [Slaanesh](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Slaanesh), the god "She who thirsts"?

[image: Slaanesh-153102-SweetAngel.jpg]

Comment: Probably could use a little more context... where is this image from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a picture originally from [kidkidkidkid](http://kidkidkidkid.deviantart.com/art/DW-IV-Final-Illustration-123090872) on Deviant Art. It is not Slaanesh. It's not even Warhammer 40,000 related. It was a concept for [Dominance War IV](http://www.dominancewar.com/2010/en/index.php).

Slaanesh by lore is supposed to be very androgynous to the point of being very disturbing and at the same time, irresistibly alluring. The gender of Slaanesh's name is even mixed with the Eldar calling him, Slaanesha - "She who thirsts".